A $H^1$-$\sigma$-finite metric space that will have infinite $H^1$-measure under every homeomorphism
This is not a question, technically — apologies. It is an example that I really wanted to share.
Let $H^1$ denote the Haudorff measure of dimension 1.

Proposition: There exists a locally compact metric space $X$ that is a countable union of subsets $X_i$ with $H^1(X_i)<\infty$ and for every homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$ onto another metric space it holds that $H^1(Y)=\infty$.

I find this interesting becasue it is not common to see a metric property being preserved under homeomorphisms, which have no regard for the metric structure whatsoever.

Question: Are you aware of other such examples where some metric quantity becomes a topological invariant? (I rule out quantities that are invariant merely by their definition — e.g. one can take some notion of dimension and infimize it over all metric spaces that are homeomorphic to a given one. Obviously it will become invariant. I do not want examples of this nature.)

Proof of Proposition: Let $X$ be the following subset of the plane:
$$\{(x,1/x): x>0\} \cup \{(1/n,y): n \in \mathbb N, 0\le y \le n\} \cup \{(0,y): y\ge 0\}.$$
It is easy to see that $X$ is connected but not path-connected. It is also locally compact. These properties will be preserved under any homeomorphism.
It is true that if a connected set (in a metric space) has finite $H^1$ measure then it is path-connected. (“Reference will be added.”)
Let the metric space $Y$ be a homeomprphic image of $X$. If $Y$ had finite $H^1$, then by the previous fact, it would have to be path-connected. However, we know it is not path-connected (since $X$ is not). This proves that $Y$ has infinite $H^1$ measure.

Corollary: The space $X \subset \mathbb R^2$ in the proof above will have infinite $H^1$ measure under any other metric structure on $\mathbb R^2$ as long as the identity map is a homeomorphism between the new topology and the standar planar topology.


Your "proposition" is wrong.

Listening… please explain.

OK, start with the identity homeomorphism $f: X\to X$ preserving the metric. As your next example, rescale the metric by a constant factor...

Ok,but constant times infinity is still infinity. Am I missing a point?

Sorry, I misread your statement, ignore my earlier comments.

No problem. I understand: it looks a weird statement bc “well, just shrink the space, right!” You can even shrink with different scales at different location. For example all of real line is homeo to the segment from 0 to 1. That is the whole point of the example. It is quite surprising!
